# Custom validator error with FromGroup

Tags: angular, validation, typescript, angular4-forms

The problem when I used custom validator with second FormGroup.

I verified my familiar with FormBuilder, I used Custom validator to verify my confirm password, but when I would access to password value I have a problem with the FormGroup.

Code of component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {confirmPasswordValidator} from './strong-password.validator';


@Component({
  selector: 'connexion-app',
  templateUrl: './connexion.component.html'
})
export class ConnexionComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;


  constructor(protected fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: this.fb.group({
        firstname: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(25)])],
        lastname: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(25)])]
      }),
      email: ['', Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$')],
      verification: this.fb.group({
        password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])],
        passwordConfirm: ['', confirmPasswordValidator()]
      })
    });
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  save(x: any) {
    console.log(x);
  }

}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jeaa5.png)

Code of html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(form.value)">
  <div formGroupName="name">
    <input formControlName="firstname" placeholder="firstname">
    <input formControlName="lastname" placeholder="lastname">
  </div>
  <input formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">

  <div formGroupName="verification">
    <input formControlName="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <input formControlName="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm" placeholder="passwordConfirm">
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<p>Value: {{ form.value | json }}</p>
<p>Validation status: {{ form.status }}</p>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz0Rf.png)

Code of Custom Validator:

```
import {AbstractControl, ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';

export function confirmPasswordValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    const pswd = control.value;
    const passwordConfirm = control.root.value.verification.password;
    return (pswd === passwordConfirm) ? null : {'strongPasswordError': {pswd}};
  };
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TfSd.png)

The problem:

> core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'password' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'password' of undefined
>       at FormControl.eval [as validator] (strong-password.validator.ts:6)
>       at FormControl.AbstractControl._runValidator (forms.es5.js:2720)
>       at FormControl.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.es5.js:2688)
>       at new FormControl (forms.es5.js:3011)
>       at FormBuilder.control (forms.es5.js:5863)
>       at FormBuilder._createControl (forms.es5.js:5905)
>       at eval (forms.es5.js:5887)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at FormBuilder._reduceControls (forms.es5.js:5886)
>       at FormBuilder.group (forms.es5.js:5845)
>       at FormControl.eval [as validator] (strong-password.validator.ts:6)
>       at FormControl.AbstractControl._runValidator (forms.es5.js:2720)
>       at FormControl.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.es5.js:2688)
>       at new FormControl (forms.es5.js:3011)
>       at FormBuilder.control (forms.es5.js:5863)
>       at FormBuilder._createControl (forms.es5.js:5905)
>       at eval (forms.es5.js:5887)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at FormBuilder._reduceControls (forms.es5.js:5886)
>       at FormBuilder.group (forms.es5.js:5845)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
>       at eval (zone.js:873)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
>       at  defaultErrorLogger @ core.es5.js:1020 ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1080 next @ core.es5.js:4503
>   schedulerFn @ core.es5.js:3635 SafeSubscriber.**tryOrUnsub @
>   Subscriber.js:239 SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:186
>   Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:127 Subscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.js:91 Subject.next @ Subject.js:56 EventEmitter.emit @
>   core.es5.js:3621 (anonymous) @ core.es5.js:3912 ZoneDelegate.invoke @
>   zone.js:392 Zone.run @ zone.js:142 NgZone.runOutsideAngular @
>   core.es5.js:3844 onHandleError @ core.es5.js:3912
>   ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:396 Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:158
>   _loop_1 @ zone.js:702 api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:711 drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:610 Promise resolved (async)
>   scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:585 ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @
>   zone.js:414 Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:236 Zone.scheduleMicroTask @
>   zone.js:256 scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:871
>   ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:981
>   PlatformRef_.*bootstrapModuleWithZone @ core.es5.js:4537
>   PlatformRef*.bootstrapModule @ core.es5.js:4522 (anonymous) @
>   main.ts:11 ../../../../../src/main.ts @ main.bundle.js:207
>   __webpack_require** @ inline.bundle.js:55 0 @ main.bundle.js:222
>   **webpack_require** @ inline.bundle.js:55 webpackJsonpCallback @ inline.bundle.js:26 (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vMYa.png)

Environment:
Angular version: 4.4.6,
Angular CLI: 1.5,
Node version: v8.7.0.

Comment: In SO we do not want images of your code, we want the code as text

Comment: Try using `control.get('password').value`? See [this article](https://scotch.io/@ibrahimalsurkhi/match-password-validation-with-angular-2).

Comment: ** I tried your solution, but the problem has been changed to: **
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at FormControl.eval [as validator] (strong-password.validator.ts:6)
    at FormControl.AbstractControl._runValidator (forms.es5.js:2720)
    at FormControl.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.es5.js:2688)
    at new FormControl (forms.es5.js:3011)
    at FormBuilder.control (forms.es5.js:5863)
    at FormBuilder._createControl (forms.es5.js:5905)

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I resolved the problem :

We need same changes in Component and Validators like this:

Validator:

```
import {AbstractControl, ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';

export function confirmPasswordValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    return (control.get('password').value === control.get('passwordConfirm').value) ? null : {'strongPasswordError': true};
  };
}
```

Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, FormControl, AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {confirmPasswordValidator} from './strong-password.validator';


@Component({
  selector: 'connexion-app',
  templateUrl: './connexion.component.html'
})
export class ConnexionComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;


  constructor(protected fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: this.fb.group({
        firstname: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(25)])],
        lastname: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(25)])]
      }),
      email: ['', Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$')],
      verification: this.fb.group({
        password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])],
        passwordConfirm: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])]
      }, {validator: confirmPasswordValidator()}),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  save(x: any) {
    console.log(x);
  }

}
```